# Retina Images on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was browsing other Stack Exchange sites and found that some support retina images. For example https://academia.stackexchange.com

Since returning to Stack Overflow it was noticeable that the images are fuzzy, I know that this doesn't affect everybody - but I am sure that developers on this site are using the latest technology.

The most obvious fuzzy images are the upvote, downvote arrows and the main logo.

> [image: Stack Overflow]<- SO | Academia -> [image: Academia]

Are there any plans to support retina images? If not, I'd like to request this feature.

Comment: Not everyone that accesses this site uses the latest technology. There are a great many users who are accessing this site from countries where the latest technology is still far too expensive, so they use what they can cobble together.

Comment: Have to remember that in some area's the bandwith for the retina images can be a big burden.

Comment: @Will - Correct - but unfortunately iOS development without a mac is hard. I was using terminology I am familiar to.

Comment: *tears hair out* Retina isn't even the highest DPI screen out there anymore!  AAAAAGH!

Comment: Also correct...

Comment: Please remember that a) there's no need for extreme clarity in the up/down vote images (as long as you can tell them apart), b) mobile users often have limited bandwidth, and wasting it on images that are any larger than necessary (or unneeded images altogether) can be somewhat restrictive and perhaps even costly, and c) adding support for hi-res images will also mean that users will include them in their questions as well, also causing bandwidth and data issues. (The last in particular is an issue for network administrators on corporate sites.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The design team is on it.  Bear with us; there's a lot on their list and there are quite a few sites to re-do.

Comment: I recall this being the answer quite some time ago: I understand that it takes time, but I'd think that Stack Overflow would be pretty high up on the list.