# Ability to quickly set an image upload to 1:2 or 1:3 scale to handle retina/super retina images

Tags: feature-request

Have a look at [UIView w/UITextView that moves with UIScrollView's dismiss interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424428/uiview-w-uitextview-that-moves-with-uiscrollviews-dismiss-interactive)

If you spend any time working in the iOS tag, and probably the Android tag too, almost every post with device screenshots end up unmanageably large. This is thanks to modern devices having at least 2x, sometimes >3x screen pixel ratio.

According to the Help docs, the solution to this is to upload your image, then painstakingly copy/paste the imgur url into an `<img>` tag. Here's the full step-by-step process:

1. Click the image upload button
2. Select your image
3. Wait for it to upload to imgur
4. Scroll to the bottom of your post where the footnote link has been placed
5. Copy out the url to the image (or cut) and delete the remaining footnote reference text
6. Find the footnote ref in your body, and replace it with `<img src="url" width="arbitrary width">`
7. Play around with the arbitrary width until the screenshot looks manageable.

OK, deep breath. Don't get me wrong - this works. And we're all developers (right?) so we should be able to do this pretty easily.

But the truth is, this is awful to do.

It's slow, cumbersome, leaves a lot of room for error, and even then, you *still* have to know that this is possible - which for new users (and even some old hats!) is pretty obscure. I've ended up losing images when I accidentally copied or cut the wrong thing and undo doesn't always work reliably.

So what can we do? The design team has been working on this [since 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270727/retina-images-on-stack-overflow?rq=1), but that was a long time ago - maybe they need our help?

Seems to me there are several options, each involving a varying degree of complexity.

1. Add some informative text when uploading images that helps raise awareness about use of the `<img>` tag. (Easy, but surprise! Now everyone under the rep cap knows how to circumvent the rep cap)
2. Add a scaling tool to the image uploader (either a slider or buttons that reduce the size to 1/2 or 1/3 original size)
3. Add some intelligent auto-scaling to images that are narrow and tall
4. Add a scale property to the screenshot markdown, e.g. `![1][screenshot][0.5]` or some such.
5. Draw attention to imgur's built in [scaling API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298818/detailed-info-on-imgurs-automatic-image-resizing-service) so that posters can know to use this feature when uploading. **The one downside to using this feature, is that the images are reduced, and the quality is noticeably poorer.**

Comment: We're programmers.  We don't need no stinkin' UI.

Comment: Hahha except, @RobertHarvey, we're programmers. We're inherently lazy and don't like repetitive tasks.

Comment: @remus, any GUI encourages repetitive tasks versus writing a script and being done with it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi except in this case you can't write a script that somehow magically knows when an image should be scaled ;)

Comment: Folks can we look at this one again? Since there's no concept of bounty in meta, I don't know how else to draw attention to it.

Comment: Related: [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405)

Comment: Exactly @makyen - at the very least this should be obvious when uploading an image.

Comment: Hey @RobertHarvey maybe you can help? I'm trying to draw attention to this post - I think there's still merit in pursuing it.

Comment: @brandonscript: Post a bounty.

Comment: @RobertHarvey would love to... but don't know how to do that on meta? There's no bounty option for me.

Comment: @brandonscript: Well, you edited the question, so it should be on the front page for awhile.

Comment: Bounties are not possible on Meta.

Comment: Ah, yeah, didn't think so.

Comment: Bounties are possible on Meta SE. Just sayin'. @Stijn.

Comment: @TRiG yes but MSE is a special case.

Comment: Wow, still no progress here. I'm deeply impressed.