# Simpler image upload?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I've often wondered why SO doesn't have simpler image upload when writing a question or answer?

Fact,

As of 2018, pretty much every web page that let you write something in a box and include diagrams, pictures etc, indeed has simple drag and drop for the images.

(This is ubiquitous, but for a good example just think of when you write an issue on github.  To add a diagram etc you just drag it in from your desktop.)

Drag in the image, resize it, if possible have write-on for notes, etc, and naturally the software should deal with problems like retina, etc.

SO has lots of top programmers and generally leads technologically, so it doesn't add-up.

Comment: One thing, just one of the points I mention in passing there is the (hilarious) "Apple 144" problem.  {Which is so simple to fix it's probably just an option somewhere in the chain of tools SO seems to be using for images?}  I observe someone already asked about this (obviously, years ago, it's such an old problem) .. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273109/294884

Comment: Not sure we need to make it _easier_ for people to post ginormous screenshots of uselessly small pieces of their broken code.

Comment: I'd try to make it harder. The drap & drop target should move around the screen while a flashing text asks you if you are really sure you need that 'code as an image' bmp...

Comment: A quite impressive option is available in a forum I frequent: *copy and paste*. There, done! I doubt though that it could work with SO's otherwise remarkably easy to use Markdown editor. That forum uses Jive and I hate it from the bottom of my guts. But ... simply *pasting* images ...

Comment: Fair enough, man.  I hope you see my point though.  Programming is an entirely visual, time-and-space, 3D exercise.  There's nothing more "mentally visual" than programming.  You can't do anything without drawing diagrams.  Anyway - fair enough.   The masses have spoken !

Comment: I mean, I agree broadly that the website needs feature work. But I don't think that more images are a pathway to question quality success.

Comment: @Fattie I think they were making a humours jab at people who post code as images and not just as plain text... Not for people who legitimately use images to illustrate their questions with a wire frame or similar

Comment: _"Why is it that SO has 1950s technology for images in posts?"_ If SO did have that kind of technology, I'd be seriously impressed you managed to attach a image to this question.

Comment: That other question you linked about resizing, _that_ I can get behind, for sure. But most of the time, at least in the tags I follow, I don't see questions _helped_ by having images. They're generally filler to my mind.

Comment: What's wrong with the current drag-and-drop support in the image uploader?

Comment: Mis-using images is a separate issue. No matter if it's easy or hard to post an image of code. (As a matter of fact, I find it *more work* to post an image of code, over simply select text and paste it in.)

Comment: Fair enough guys.  It does seem hard to understand your view though: put it this way.  Consider, every minute of the day you use google docs/drive etc. with your colleagues. Of course you just drop images in there.  **Imagine if google docs changed to the ancient clunky system SO seems to be using?** You'd just find it bizarre and be asking "why??"   *Given that* SO allows images, what possible reason does SO have to be using the totally archaic system it has?  i don't get it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find _"the ancient clunky system SO seems to be using"_ to be a gross exaggeration. Frankly, it's insulting. Sure, there are some improvements that could be made, but the current system is ___far___ from bad. It's not even remotely close to _"archaic"_.

Comment: SO is not a charity. Employees must be paid competitive salaries. Funding is limited. That's why SO doesn't always have the latest, greatest features.

Comment: Hey @Cerbrus, i just can't agree.  It's **incredibly** out of date.  We do more apps than WWW, but imagine if you had a client that had you do a web site, and there was a spot where you could put in text and images.  And it used the system SO currently uses.  That would be **a joke**.  Everyone would look at you funny.  It wouldn't even be like "a placeholder".  it would look like something weird was afoot, or there was some specific strange reason you did it.  Anyways cheers ..

Comment: What's this "WWW" you speak of? All you're doing is, for lack of a better word, insult the current implementation. You're ranting. How about you come up with a proper solution? Link us to a markdown editor that fixes this so-called archaic system. A editor that has the same features we currently have, but "fixes" image uploads.

Comment: @Fattie What specifically is weird/outdated about it? It seems like a pretty standard wysiwyg editor imo

Comment: hey @Stijn - that doesn't make sense on there levels.  (1) SO is indeed an example of an *incredibly* cash successful www enterprise, which (2) indeed, has *awesome, spectacular* technology and a a paragon of excellence and solidity, and (the very reason I'm asking) (3) the feature is so trivial it's highly incongruous that SO has not updated.

Comment: You know what would help though? Posting a normal and friendly feature request here on MSO. Without all the rudeness your current post has.

Comment: hey @George - what ?!  If I'm not mistaken they're using some *3rd party* to handle image upload, it's a joke.  Use basically any other site (surely you use github or goog docs) to see ordinary drag-in image handling.

Comment: The more you say "trivial" the less I think you know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Fattie: Stop shouting how trivial it is, and give us a editor that has the ___same___ features ___and___ a better image upload. Put your money where your mouth is. Just give us some proper examples.

Comment: @Fattie _what you see is what you get_ it's what editors like that are called. That's because those websites are for storing files, there's nothing wrong with using a 3rd party to store images so I don't see what that's got to do with anything. The editor allows drag and drop, all you have to do is click a button, are you suggesting to just remove the button and allow users to drag an image in? I'm not against improving the image upload it's just you're not being very clear on whats _wrong_ with the current one and what you're recommending to improve it.

Comment: hi @Stijn - good grief, it had *one joke* ("1950s technology"), sure I edited it out. Is there something else I'm missing?   It's not really a feature request, I'm more wondering the reason for this curiosity?

Comment: @Fattie: What about calling the technology archaic? What about consistently claiming it's trivial to implement? Do you have any idea what it takes to _build_ a proper image upload?

Comment: hey @Cerbrus ... ??????  I mean, are "google docs" and "github" not enough?  Huh?

Comment: Which Github editor are you talking about that has support for drag & dropping images? Google Docs obviously doesn't count. As far as I can tell it is not a code-oriented markdown editor.

Comment: hey @yivi, on github just post an issue or comment.

Comment: @yivi: When you open a new issue, you can drag-drop images directly onto the textarea you are writing in. But it also took me several trials to find that thing. The feature request would be way better without the whole ranting and a clear proposal what should be added and how.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks @BDL. Still, I don't think anything particularly wrong or "archaic" about SO image upload process and I think it is easy enough for anyone to use. IMO, very little would be gained by making it _even easier_. But I admit that the general tone of this post may have predisposed me against this idea.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Stack Overflow already has a drag-and-drop image uploader. It requires **one extra click** to spawn the image-upload modal. This is literally the only difference between SO's editor, which you call "archaic", an "ancient clunky system", and  "a joke", and Github's editor, which you seem to praise. A **single mouse click**.  Besides that mouse click, both uploaders are **identical**. Are you not aware that SO *has* a drag-and-drop image uploader already, and that it's functionally identical to Github's?

Comment: ?  ("single clicks" are UX and computing. Actual inline/immediate wysiwyg drag and drop is a completely different UX category than click-to-do-something functions.)

Comment: And that single click makes a system "archaic"... You know what's archaic? The human condition. Why don't you replace yourself with an android?

Comment: And you're surprised users have a hard time taking this question / feature request / rant seriously... -.-

Comment: @Fattie Github is not wysiwyg. You drag an image onto it, and you get a bit of markdown dropped into your post representing an image, *exactly* like SO. Neither system is wysiwyg, they're both *markdown* which is inherently *not* wysiwyg.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange's current system to embed images in one's questions and answers is working pretty darn well.

The upload is intuitive and considering Stack Exchange isn't in the business of document management, the editor is pretty well fleshed out.

You mention examples like Google Docs and GitHub.

Google is a ***massive*** company on a whole different scale than SE that can afford to dedicate a *large* team of their employees to fleshing out any portion of their products. For them, document management *is* a core product.

GitHub uses a [massive list](http://github.com/collections/projects-that-power-github) of external tools and libraries. Frankly, I prefer SE's editor.

Don't get me wrong. Supporting drag&drop or copy-paste on the input field would be *great*. However, it's nowhere near as trivial to implement or standard as you make it out to be. The current implementation isn't anywhere close to archaic.

Comment: The perfect thing would be SO's editor with an additional feature where you can upload images by just dropping them into the textarea (without having to open a new sub-window).

Comment: @BDL: I agree. I've slightly updated my answer.

Comment: draw.io? What the blazes is that? I think you’re overestimating what people use “all the time”.

Comment: I see. You’re comparing a Q/A site’s text input field to a program who’s core business is _drawing lines_. Completely different scope. Talk about unrealistic expectations, @Fattie.

Comment: Huh?  I was agreeing with your (further) idea about inline "paste" of image fragments.  (Great idea - fantastic thinking - totally agree with you.)   Sorry if my sentence structure wasn't clear, but I then went on to say "And since that extension is such a great idea, furthermore perhaps in the future we could have SVG handling, and what about adding line-drawing on top..."  I think you're just being grumpy now, old boy  :)

Comment: Technology moves incredibly quickly - notice the latest "Apple" adds on TV.  Ordinary users now demand to be able to **M.R. animate their face with a pink unicorn** while talking, *on a device that is, really, just "a telephone"*.  I can't keep up!  :O

Comment: _" really it should be like <...> draw.io"_ < no it shouldn't. Different scope.

Comment: Huh?  Pretty much every single time I create an answer on SO, I want to add a diagram.  It's the most obvious thing in the world.  I mean, setting aside algorithm / comp sci questions (where you just have to use diagrams) it's barely possible to answer questions involving visual interfaces, without arrows-n-crap!  ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333832/294884 )  Anyway, **I understand fully your points man**, thanks for taking the time here!  Really. I'll leave it to you, to try to encourage us to get back to work, right!  Heh!  Cheers, happy new year

Comment: In my 1289 answers on SO so far, I've never really had the need to post a diagram... Don't assume your use is typical.

Comment: @Fattie This is uniquely a **you** thing. You're one of the only users I've ever encountered who adds diagrams to their answers. Similar to Cerbrus, I don't recall ever adding a diagram to my ~3200 answers. Jon Skeet appears to have included images (of any kind) in a whopping [22 of his ~36,000 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+url%3Ai.stack.imgur.com).

Comment: fascinating, that's cool how you can use the search man.  thanks for that.  yeah I guess it's not so relevant to java / DB / whatever? dudes.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS+url%3Ai.stack.imgur.com  cheers @meagar

Comment: It's funny how people live in different worlds, I can't even imaging HAVING a qa on SO for modern topics, unless you have *animation*, for goodness sake - far less images and diagrams!  example @meagar ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068198/294884 Heh!  Indeed, the fact that you can't embed playing videos (correct me if I'm wrong) nor easily add or make animations, or "twitch-like" screen capture of workflow, is a huge time waste when using SO.

Comment: @Fattie You want something that SO is not (and IMO should never be). I don't want to scrub through a screencast to try and find my answers, I want a straight forward, human-readable, *searchable* answer. There are lots of places you can go to watch screencasts, SO does not have to be one of them.  SO would be an absolutely useless cesspool if we encouraged videos and media in our answers.

Comment: @Fattie you keep expanding your requirements. Video? Are you kidding? What’s next? You can’t imagine questions and answers without Emoji? Without live chat? Maybe what you want isn’t quality Q/A, but a _forum_.

Comment: hi @meagar, hmm, sometimes these "internet conversations" can be wildly confusing -because topics are instantly dropped, and new topics come up, based on passing elements of conversation.  You showed us how to count how many QA use images - I think **100,000** for "iOS" is that right? That's fascinating, good one.  ***In passing*** , again that is ***in passing***, I mentioned how interesting that is, and indeed you often need animations (for goodness sake!) in QA for topics like pathfinding. You then say something like "You Fattie want SO to be a video site!" There's no real response to that!

Comment: @Fattie Your words: *"the fact that you can't embed playing videos (correct me if I'm wrong) nor easily add or make animations, or "twitch-like" screen capture of workflow, is a huge time waste when using SO"*

Comment: I really don't know what to say to your latest comment, @Cerbrus.  You give the impression that next you'll say something like "ah hah, you mention VR, Fattie! Fattie wants SO to be in VR!".

Comment: The fact that you'd say "video, are you kidding" ....... is a bit whacky. To take a random example, it's really commonplace when dealing with questions about animation in UX (I just answered one, for goodness sake!) to have a short video, screen capture, to show what is under discussion. ("animated gifs" are relatively popular on SO! for questions about animes in UX in droid/ios.)  {I don't know how to make them, so I've never put one in an answer! :)  }  Surely, in your own work, your team *constantly* shares videos (and say things like Lona and Lottie) when working? Anyway let's chill, geesh

Comment: My point is that you're throwing all kinds of ridiculous requirements around that really have no business on SO. SO is for ___programming___ Q/A. That doesn't "require" videos. It doesn't require animations. It requires well written answers.

Comment: The only videos we share at work are NSFW and in a non-work chat group. UX is more often than not off-topic for SO. It's often opinion based, and more often than not, not a programming issue.

Comment: "UX is more often than not off-topic for SO. It's often opinion based, and more often than not, not a programming issue"   hi @cerbrus  I feel we're talking at cross-purposes.  I don't mean "discussing UX, as on the UX site".   consider this QA I just answered ... about how to do "transition animations" in iOS.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081504/294884  Funnily enough, I **really, really needed to include an animated gif**, heh!  Showing the difference between the "push along" anime of iOS and the custom "over-off" one. .. cont ...

Comment: _"I really, really needed to include an animated gif, heh!"_ So why didn't you? Also, did that question really need a 25th answer?

Comment: I totally realize I'm as "guilty as you" as endlessly replying, but we really have to break it off and get back to work and drinking, man!  :)  Again, funnily enough, on that example question I **literally, actually**  needed to include an either animated gif, simply a video, or a screen-capture type action, to explain.  I personally hate those "video-tutorials" as opposed to text tutorials; that's not what I'm talking about. But, really, it's oddball not to realize that 1 images, 2 diagrams, 3 various animated-stuff is not just completely normal in computer-related QA. Again, cheers for now!

Comment: Again, why didn't you add a `.gif` if it was that critical? You're not replying to my comments. You're just repeating yourself without answering me.

Comment: "Also, did that question really need a 25th answer?" seriously dude -  you're just wildly veering to totally disparate topics, each time I wholly answer a point you bring up :)  Yes, obviously, - if you feel the need to discuss that question there - it was a very old QA, and the systems in iOS have greatly changed; none of the answers actually explained how to implement UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.  (Correct me if I'm wrong.)  It's - no offense - offensive if you're going to criticize an answer that took maybe 90 minutes to assemble, and is the only modern working answer there!

Comment: The time it took to assemble an answer says nothing about the quality of the answer, to be honest.

Comment: oh boy, say I had a good idea, why don't you click delete on this "answer" @Cerbrus - and then I can delete this whole QA. (As you know, I can't click "delete" on the overall question, while, there's an answer.)  This would be more satisfactory for the overall group, and we can continue our interesting discussion elsewhere or whatever.  Good plan right??

Comment: No, I disagree.

Comment: Why would we delete this? We have the perfect post to show to the next person coming with a similar request that it's something the community really doesnt feel like it needs. And BTW I think that Cerbrus' point on that answer, @Fattie, is that if a video was necessary but you didn't include one... either the video isn't necessary (your answer is valid and good quality, even video-less... correct? If so then it isn't 'literally necessary') Or that the answer's quality isn't up to our standards