# How many posts have pictures?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, images

I was wondering **how many posts have image(s)** in them? Is it possible to query that?

This comes from trying to understand how much people *care* to put pictures in SO, and trying to **gather data** for **discussions on this subject**.

It's nice to take a side and form an opinion based on actual numbers.

---

*Bonus: How are the numbers from regular SO and meta SO compared to each other?*

<sub>**Footnote:** I'm not judging wether the images are good (diagram) or bad (screenshot of code), but in case that's to consider, maybe just counting images in answers (as they *should* not include as many code) I guess would be fine.</sub>

Comment: ... From https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361361/simpler-image-upload#comment544352_361361

Comment: I'm running `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE Body LIKE '%<img%'` in SEDE. That will include posts where the <img> tag is inside code, but it'll give a nice base figure.

Comment: @Glorfindel I was thinking something among those lines too, but I'll wait for the more experienced pros to do that, as I'm not actually qualified.

Comment: @Glorfindel but wouldn't that include codes that consists of it? Not really images...

Comment: We can further limit to look for `like '%//i.stack.imgur.com%'` to only include the images provided via SO's editor.  This would probably handle the vast majority of cases without code conflicts. @Glorfindel

Comment: Yeah. As I mentioned, I'm not qualified for this. It would be **nice** if people post answers so we can see the **different approaches**.

Comment: I would also exclude closed questions (maybe limited to "why isn't this code work" as the closing reason), since they can identify questions with improperly used images (e.g. images of code).

Comment: Seeing how people reacted to this in the comments, I'd say they are willing to participate in this and know the results. As this' yet to receive a comment against, so it would be nice to see the pov of the downvoter as to why this is useles ^^.

Comment: @FirstOne: Don't worry too much about downvotes on Meta.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not. But such question with not text response is pretty ambiguous (vote-wise).

Comment: Too many.  Saw a good answer with an animated gif this morning, could not bring myself to vote for it.  Odd phenomena lately btw, seems there is an entire new generation that never had their eyes assaulted by web v1.0

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh 1.0... _Blink_ and you missed it. (I wish)

Comment: As other people said, do not fret votes in Meta (or in main, for that matter). Possible reasons for downvotes that I can think of: dowvoters could feel that you could have conducted your own research, that the number of images is not important and it could be argued that is almost impossible to derive a meaningful reading from this data, that no actionable course is proposed in the question, that Tim lost his keys, etc. Personally, I do not have a dog in this fight. I vote _+0 meh_. :P

Comment: Good Lord, this question is expanding :)  @HansPassant , was it this question .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354842/increase-element-padding-as-browser-width-decreases ?  Which question was it?

Comment: I don't see how you can even ask a question like this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698636/image-in-cashapelayer-do-not-fit-in-swift (random search example from 100s) without using an anime, video or whatever.  There seems to be some confusion here, it would be as if someone said "let's use 'Text' on SO" and you blokes said "oh, boy, that 'text' stuff is used in those internet cat meme things - let's not have that!"  :)

Comment: @Fattie: It already has an animated gif, and that seems to be working just fine. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 7):

As there are so many posts on Stack Overflow already, SEDE queries to analyze this often time out. Therefore, I looked at the posts from last December, as it's the *ratio* that matters most.

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/777323/image-statistics?FromDate=2017-12-01&TillDate=2017-12-31), of the 390k posts created in December 2017, 22k or 27k (depending on what you count) have images (or something that looks like an image) in them. That amounts to 5.7% resp. 7%.

For [Meta Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/777323/image-statistics?FromDate=2017-12-01&TillDate=2017-12-31), the numbers are 167 (with images)/870 (total) = 19%.

You can play around with the dates to see if there's a trend, but if you choose a large enough interval, the query will time out.

Comment: I would add to this answer _what_ you consider to be _"having images in them"_.

Comment: @FirstOne 5.7% contains `i.stack.imgur.com` and 7% contains `<img` . IMO, the linked SEDE query already provide a ton of details

Comment: @abccd I'd say we consider the SEDE link as any other link: questions should include any necessary information - and limiting what's considered an image is important, imo.

Comment: @FirstOne: SEDE is a Stack Exchange resource. One that won't go down while Stack Overflow is still standing. So SEDE isn't considered an "external" resource.

Comment: You could just do a site search of *url:i.stack.imgur.com* and optionally apply created or is:q and is:a etc...

Comment: eg: *url:i.stack.imgur.com created:2017-12* gives you 27,809 results and taking off the created filter gives you 1,319,128 results

Comment: That'd work but it 1) includes images linked as plain text 2) excludes images from external sources and 3) cannot be combined within SEDE results. But it's good to have it as another source (especially as the OP was concerned SEDE isn't reliable enough).

Comment: @Glorfindel given it seems consistent with SEDE, is more representative of those uploading images and I imagine given the purpose of it being an indicator of how many images there are - even if it's a couple of percent out of being totally accurate (whatever that means in this context) *shrugs*

Comment: Looks like in December - 25,328 questions with a potential image were created, 21,528 remain after removing deleted ones and 20,395 are still open...